# how to remove the evernote and dropbox publisher action

Tags: salesforce1-app, global-actions

In the new Salesforce 1 app, we are seeing a publisher action for Evernote and Dropbox.
These do not appear as items that you could remove from the publisher actions section on the page layouts.

Does anyone know a way to fix this? We don't want these specific publisher actions there.

[image: Evernote and Dropbox not showing as actions]

Answer (score 4):

We got an answer from Salesforce on this issue.
Turns out this is a known issue at the time and they are working on it to get these removed soon.

No way at this time that you can remove them yourself.

You might want to contact Salesforce support if it is a real show stopper issue at this time.